# How to stop all background processes in android?

Tags: android

I hope to stop all backgroud processes.

I got to know that `adb shell am kill-all` may do this job. I exit one application by pressing BACK,

then I enter `adb shell am kill-all`, However, I find the process by entering `adb shell ps | grep packagename`.

Does `adb shell am kill-all` really work?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to kill background process with adb shell command. You can use some task manager in play store. 
I also developed a task manager by myself, there are source codes:
https://code.google.com/p/my-test-project-lion/